# How can I find release schedules of foreign movies in China?

Tags: scheduling

I currently live in China and love to go to the cinema on a regular basis.

However, due to government protectionism and a fear of foreign culture invading, only about 30-40 foreign movies are released a year here.

This means that only a select few movies get past the board for approval. I've done some research (i.e. google searching) and I understand that many movies don't get approved until maybe 2-3 months before they're going to be released here.

Despite this, I was really hoping that someone could point me in a the direction of a predicted release of foreign movies in China so that I could start to get suitably excited / disappointed if movies that I want to see are going to be released here.

Comment: http://movie.douban.com/coming

I apologise for wasting time - but I did find a Chinese language link. I'll leave this here in case anybody else finds it useful

Comment: Not wasting time. You should put it as an answer, but it may be volatile information ... may not be available "tomorrow" as a viable source.

Comment: I agree, if it's possible, you can provide your own answer and confirm it, or maybe a mod could do this? Metadata pages can show that the question was answered which is helpful to visitors.

Comment: Ok, so I added my comment as an answer. I was limited by reputation wait time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://movie.douban.com/coming

I did find a Chinese language link. I'll leave this here in case anybody else finds it useful